# Permanently show hidden channels in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, chat, microsoft-teams

Moving from Slack to Microsoft Teams, one of the most annoying changes is the liberal use of "hidden" channels. I'm frequently having to click into the "3 hidden channels" submenu:

[image: 3 hidden channels]

Selecting a channel from the hidden list temporarily moves in to the main list, where that channel name is then shown in italics. But the channel immediately hides itself again once you click away.

This is especially annoying when there is "1 hidden channel". You could *just show me that channel* in the same space required to tell me it's hidden...

[image: 1 hidden channel]

I hate how my channels list is constantly moving as channels show and hide. I hate having to click into the submenu to show my channels. I see no logic to how channels are determined to be hidden.

How can I permanently disable hidden channels in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: [UserVoice: Don't hide channels in the "More channels" dropdown when there is space to display them.](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/19079887-don-t-hide-channels-in-the-more-channels-dropdow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the "hidden channels" submenu, hover over a channel name.

This will present the option to "Show" the channel, along with an eye icon.

[image: Show channel Microsoft Teams]

After Showing a channel, it will remain non-hidden in your Teams channels sidebar.